# Cannot use r.recode directly in powershell

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, powershell

I am trying to use elements of `GRASS` in the terminal (PowerShell). I have added the relevant directories to `$env:path` so that `get-command r.recode` returns an executable. However, when I try and run `r.recode --help`, for example, I just jump to the next line and nothing happens. I get the same result if I try and use `r.recode input=intput.tif rules=rules.txt output=output.tif`; where `input.tif` is a valid `.tif` file, `rules.txt` contains valid recoding rules and `output.tif` does not exist. How do I set up PowerShell access to `GRASS` commands? Note: I am trying to use the executables that shipped with `QGIS` and following along with the `log` output to structure my commands.

Thanks.